# Ad not loaded after request

Tags: android, admob

I am testing Ads in an Android app.
I want a button to be shown when the ad is loaded, and then click on the button to show the ad.

My issue is that the ad is never loaded.

This is my code so far:

```
 MobileAds.initialize(getActivity(), "ca-app-pub-***");
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-ca-app-pub-***");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        btnOfertar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
                btnOfertar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You are not showing ad. You need to add `mInterstitialAd.show();` on method `onAdLoaded()`, and edit your `mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-ca-app-pub-***");` to `mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-***");`. Also, check `LogCat` for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {

                // Add this
                mInterstitialAd.show()


                Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
                btnOfertar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Also, try using the dedicated test ad id that Google provides in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial): `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712`. If this loads properly your code should be okay.

Your actual ad might take a while to show up depending on how many requests you're getting to show the ad. Also make sure that your AdMob's payment is set up correctly.